# Is there something I can lay on my phone's screen to emulate my finger?

Tags: cell-phone

Long story short, I need to hold down a button for long periods of time for a game, and I'd really rather just put the phone down and lay a sausage on it or something, but you know... I'd rather not use food.

What else has the same effect?

Note: There exists apps that can be configured to do automatic presses, but Android phones need to be rooted in order to accomodate this kind of app. I did this, but it turns out that some banking apps refuse to run on rooted devices for security reasons, so I had to un-root.

Comment: This is not a hack but you could consider a stylus. You could also ask the game developer to add a Mario Kart 8 Deluxe style auto-press mode :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take about 12 inches of electrical wire and strip approx. 1/2" of the insulation from one end. Now wrap the exposed bare wire using a piece of aluminum foil and flatten the end of the foil a bit. I quickly  made one and took a photo to better explain it (see image below).

You can now use this to replicate your finger touching the screen.

[image]

Comment: The contact area of the aluminum ball should have a diameter of at least 5 millimeters (7/32 inch) to make sure the phone screen actually recognizes it as a finger and not a random disturbance. That's why all of the passive (not battery powered) styluses have a wide tip.

Comment: Great addition! I had a feeling it had to be a minimum width because a really narrow tip didn't work very well for me while testing it out. That's also why I said to flatten the end of the foil because I didn't know the precise specs. Thanks for clearing that up :)

Answer (score 0):

There's some pen with touch capabilities, so you can put then up to the button and put some things to not move out the pen! I used this pen sometime when there some waiting web room and I can looking all time, so I put the pen with one motor and the screen dont dispose!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Could yoy please expand on this.  A more detailed description would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have read @nnamerz' answer and it's great. Good info about the wideness of the touch.

I just found out that laying a pair of metal scissors flat on the phone also activates the touch function. I can't take a picture of it as my phone is my camera... Maybe that could be a way to "trick" the game?

I just tried in the game "Egg, Inc", and actually there is some noise,
so the button is activated then not activated in irregular patterns. This is actually a good thing in this game, as the button has to be lifted after about 10-20 seconds, until it can be pressed again. So yeah, life hack!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).